# Quadrature error estimates for $n$-rectangular finite elements in the context of elliptic second order problems

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, finite-element-method

In Ciarlet's book "Finite Element Methods for Elliptic Problems" from 1978, in Chapter 4.1 "The Effect of Numerical Integration", the following Theorem is stated and proved:

##################################

**Theorem 4.1.4**
Assume that, for some integer $k \geq 1$,
$$\forall \hat\varphi \in P_{2k-2}(\hat{K})\,,\quad \hat{E}(\hat\varphi)=0\,.$$
Then there exists a constant $C$ independent of $K\in\mathcal{T}_h$ and $h$ such that $\forall a\in W^{k,\infty}(K)$, $\forall p,p' \in P_k(K)$ it holds
$$|E_K(a\partial_ip'\partial_jp)| \leq Ch^k\|a\|_{W^{k,\infty}(K)}\|\partial_ip'\|_{W^{k-1,2}(K)}\|\partial_j p \|_{L^2(K)}\,.$$

##################################

Here, the following notation is used:

$K\in\mathcal{T}_h$ is a simplex with maximal diameter $h>0$, $\hat{K}$ is the reference simplex. For a given quadrature scheme on $\hat{K}$ with quadrature points $\hat{b}_1,\dots,\hat{b}_L$ and weights $\hat\omega_1,\dots,\hat\omega_L$, $\hat{E}(\cdot)$ is the *quadrature error functional* on $\hat{K}$, i.e.
$$\hat{E}(\hat\varphi) = \int_{\hat{K}}\hat\varphi\ \text{d}x - \sum_{l=1}^L\hat\omega_l\hat\varphi(\hat{b}_l)\,.$$
$E_K(\cdot)$ is the corresponding *quadrature error functional* on $K$, induced by the quadrature scheme on $\hat{K}$ and transformed to $K$ by an affine function. $P_k(K)$ is the space of polynomials of degree $\leq k$ on $K$.

Now towards my question: In **Exercise 4.1.7**(iii) in the same book, the reader is encouraged to show the analogue of **Theorem 4.1.4** for the case of $n$-rectangular finite elements, under the assumption that the quadrature scheme is exact for the space $Q_{2k-1}(\hat{K})$. In this case, we have the reference element $\hat{K} = [0,1]^n$, and $Q_{k}(\hat{K})$ is the space of all polynomials which are of degree $\leq k$ with respect to each one of the $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. My interpretation of this exercise is that the reader is invited to show the following:

##################################

Assume that, for some integer $k \geq 1$,
$$\forall \hat\varphi \in Q_{2k-1}(\hat{K})\,,\quad \hat{E}(\hat\varphi)=0\,.$$
Then there exists a constant $C$ independent of $K\in\mathcal{T}_h$ and $h$ such that $\forall a\in W^{k,\infty}(K)$, $\forall q,q' \in Q_k(K)$ it holds
$$|E_K(a\partial_iq'\partial_jq)| \leq Ch_K^k\|a\|_{W^{k,\infty}(K)}\|\partial_iq'\|_{W^{k-1,2}(K)}\|\partial_j q \|_{L^2(K)}\,.$$

##################################

My question is: Does anyone has an idea how to prove this? If you follow the proof of **Theorem 4.1.4**, there the problem is transformed onto the reference element $\hat{K}$, and then, with the use of the Bramble-Hilbert Lemma, the following is shown:
$$\forall \hat{a}\in W^{k,\infty}(\hat{K}),\forall \hat{v},\hat{w}\in P_{k-1}(\hat{K}):\quad |\hat{E}(\hat{a}\hat{v}\hat{w})|\leq \hat{C}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|\hat{a}|_{k-j,\infty,\hat{K}}|\hat{v}|_{j,2,\hat{K}}\right)|\hat{w}|_{0,2,\hat{K}}\,,$$
with seminorms $|u|_{t,s,K} = \sum_{|\alpha|=t}\|D^\alpha u\|_{L^s(K)}$.

However, if one wants to use a similar approach to prove **Exercise4.1.7**(iii), note that if $q\in Q_k(K)$, then $\partial_i q\in Q_k(K)\cap P_{nk-1}(K)$. Hence, the following estimate would be needed:
$$\forall \hat{a}\in W^{k,\infty}(\hat{K}),\forall \hat{v},\hat{w}\in Q_{k}(\hat{K})\cap P_{nk-1}(\hat{K}):\quad |\hat{E}(\hat{a}\hat{v}\hat{w})|\leq \hat{C}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|\hat{a}|_{k-j,\infty,\hat{K}}|\hat{v}|_{j,2,\hat{K}}\right)|\hat{w}|_{0,2,\hat{K}}\,.$$
But this estimate is not true in general: If one considers $\hat{a}$ to be constant, the right hand side vanishes, since only terms $|\hat{a}|_{s,\infty,\hat{K}}$ with $s\geq 1$ appear. On the other hand, $\hat{v}\hat{w} \notin Q_{2k-1}(\hat{K})$ in general, hence the left hand side is not zero in general. A similar, but weaker estimate can be shown, using that $\hat\varphi\hat{w}\in Q_{2k-1}(\hat{K})$ for $\hat\varphi\in P_{k-1}(\hat{K}),\hat{w}\in Q_k(\hat{K})$ together with the Bramble-Hilbert Lemma:
$$\forall \hat{a}\in W^{k,\infty}(\hat{K}),\forall \hat{v},\hat{w}\in Q_{k}(\hat{K})\cap P_{nk-1}(\hat{K}):\quad |\hat{E}(\hat{a}\hat{v}\hat{w})|\leq \hat{C}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}|\hat{a}|_{k-j,\infty,\hat{K}}|\hat{v}|_{j,2,\hat{K}}\right)|\hat{w}|_{0,2,\hat{K}}\,.$$
This, however, unfortunately contains the term $|\hat{v}|_{k,2,\hat{K}}$ on the right hand side that leads to the term $\|\partial_i q'\|_{W^{k,2}(K)}$ on the right hand side of the desired estimate, and hence is a weaker result than desired.

Under the assumption that the quadrature is exact for $Q_{2k}(\hat{K})$, a proof of the exercise seems to be within reach, by using induction over the dimension $n$, provided the quadrature scheme is of a tensor-product form. The formulation in the book however suggests that the weaker assumption ($\forall \hat\varphi \in Q_{2k-1}(\hat{K}):\quad \hat{E}(\hat\varphi)=0$) is sufficient.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thank you very much in advance!